# how to change Cypher isolation level to uncommitted

Tags: neo4j, cypher, isolation-level

it seems that neo4j opens a transaction for simple match queries.

for example:

```
match (h:Event) return min(h.date_time),max(h.date_time)
```

is it possible to change it, so it will read from uncommitted data?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html), you can execute multiple Cypher statements (queries) within the same transaction, and subsequent statements can see the uncommitted data from previous statements.

Comment: Thanks. I wish it would be simpler, such as 'nolock match'